# Fix positive $t$. Construct $a_n \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $(\inf_x \|x-a_n\|_2 + t\|x\|_1 )/\min(\|a_n\|_2,t\|a_n\|_1) \to 0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, norms, counterexamples, interpolation-spaces

For any positive number $t$, nonnegative integer $n$, and nonzero vector $a \in \mathbb R^n$, define

$$
\begin{split}
K_n(a,t) &:= \inf_{x \in \mathbb R^n} \|x-a\|_2 + t\|x\|_1,\\
M_n(a,t) &:= \min(\|a\|_2,t\|a\|_1),\\
R_n(a,t) &:= K_n(a,t)/M_n(a,t).
\end{split}
$$

**Note.** $K_n$ defines the Peetre's K-functional between $(\mathbb R^n,\ell_2)$ and $(\mathbb R^n,\ell_1)$, where the $\ell_p$ norm of a vector $x=(x^1,\ldots,x^n)$ is defined by $\|x\|_p := (\sum_i |x^i|^p)^{1/p}$.

**Question.** Is it possible to construct $a_n \in \mathbb R^n$ for each $n$, such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} R_n(a_n,t) = 0$ ?

### Motivation

Clearly, one always has $K_n(a,t) \le M_n(a,t)$ with equality when $n=1$. What is not clear is whether one can construct $a$ with growing dimension $n$ such that $K_n(a,t) \ll M_n(a,t)$ eventually.

Comment: Can you motivate this a bit? Do you know the answer for $n=1$?

Comment: I added some motivation. Also, one can compute $R_1(a,t) = \min(1,t)|a|/\min(1,t)|a|=1$ for all $a \ne 0$ and positive $t$. The problem becomes interesting in the limit $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Let's say $t=1$, to keep it simple, and wlog $\|a\|_2=1$, so $M=1$. To make $K$ small, we'd have to take $x=a+b$, $\|b\|_2<\epsilon$, but then $\|x\|_1\ge \|a+b\|_2\ge 1-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to extend Christian Remling's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432168/fix-positive-t-construct-a-n-in-mathbb-rn-such-that-inf-x-x-a-n-2#comment1112378_432168) to all real $t>0$, with an explicit lower bound on $K/M$, where $K:=K_n(a,t)$ and $M:=M_n(a,t)$.

$\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}$The key here, as in Christian Remling's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432168/fix-positive-t-construct-a-n-in-mathbb-rn-such-that-inf-x-x-a-n-2#comment1112378_432168), is the observation that $\norm x_1\ge\norm x_2$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Indeed, this observation implies
$$K
\ge\inf_{x\in\mathbb R^n}\bigl(\lvert\norm x_2-\norm a_2\rvert+t\norm x_2\bigr)
=\inf_{u\ge0}\bigl(\lvert u-\norm a_2|+tu\bigr)
=\min(1,t)\norm a_2$$
and
$$M\le\norm a_2,$$
whence
$$\frac KM\ge\min(1,t).$$
(In particular, $K\ge M$ if $t\ge1$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think this would if $t$ were now a sequence going to infinity with $n$ ? I can make this into a separate question.

Comment: @dohmatob : It is now shown that $K\ge M$ for all $t\ge1$. It is more sensible to consider small $t$.

Comment: Sorry, indeed what i meant was $t \to 0$ with $n \to \infty$. I'll make a separate question.

Comment: The case $t\to0$ has now been considered at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432410/on-the-infimal-convolution-of-two-norms-on-mathbb-rn/432411#432411

Comment: This is really interesting and insightful. Thanks.